# NestJS and TailwindCSS app to reload when I make changes to style/layout

Tags: node.js, webpack, nestjs, tailwind-css, nunjucks

I am configuring a NestJS to automatically reload whenever I make changes to the styling, e.g. add a TailwindCSS class to an HTML element.

I think I am close to achieving it because:

- I have installed webpack and the server reloads/recompiles the Typescript whenever I make changes to the code.
  `npm run start:dev` runs these scripts `"nest build --webpack --webpackPath webpack-hmr.config.js --watch"`
- When I run `npm build` (which runs `"nest build && npx tailwindcss -i ./src/assets/tailwind.css -o ./dist/tailwind.css --watch"`) and make changes to the styling, it 'rebuilds' everytime. Though `npm build` doesn't run the server...

However, I haven't worked out how to get both of these scripts working together at the same time. I need the server to reload whenever either the TypeScript or the TailwindCSS is changed.
I have tried adding `"nest build && npx tailwindcss -i ./src/assets/tailwind.css -o ./dist/tailwind.css --watch"` to the script for `npm run start:dev`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can view my solution to this on [Github](https://github.com/ZathrasXI/nestjs_nunjucks_tailwind/tree/latest). I didn't need to use webpack in the end. Just extra configuration of nunjucks in `main.ts` and `nest-cli.json`